# BNF converting to EBNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I am converting the following grammar from BNF to EBNF.

```
<race> => go <dir_list> and stop

<dir_list> =>   <dir> 
              | <dir> then <dir_list>
<dir> =>   from <point> to <point>  
         | around <point>   
         | to <point> 
<point> =>   A
           | B
           | C
```

I've done my research and i've come up with

```
<race> => go <dir_list> and stop
<dir_list> => <dir> { (then) <dir> }
<dir> => (from | around | to ) { <point> to <point> }
<point> => (A|B|C)
```

is this correct, in not can someone provide me with a solution?

Comment: `(from | around | to) { <point> to <point> }` will allow syntax like `around <point> to <point>` and `to <point> to <point>` which the original BNF did not allow. It will also allow the use of `from`, `around`, or `to` on their own without a `<point>`. And it will *not* allow `around <point>` or `to <point>` on their own. Also the parentheses around `then` are needless.

Comment: `<dir> => (from <point> to | around | to) <point>`

Comment: @Oktalist: Wouldn't that comment be more appropriate as an answer?

Comment: @Grizzly: I spose, but I wasn't confident enough that it answers the whole question

Comment: thank you that makes a little more sense